# Regarding implementation of Android internationalization

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

I have to create an Android app where we can implement internationalization? For example, suppose there is an app where we can login and move to the next page. I want to change the the language from English to Chinese, how do I do that? It should be applied to the whole application i.e the login page as well as the next page.

Please Help guys, if you have an example please do share. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions lies in using the locale of the user, and providing associated text using xml files in language specific folder.

Have strings.xml,dimens.xml,fonts.xml etc in Project--> res--> values-?? folder where "??" represents the locale of the user. if you want to support english,spanish,etc,you should have folders values-en,values-es,etc. all in the Project/res/ to support them.
You can have a look at this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html).